# Cannot reset index after grouping by PeriodIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code that parses given columns from a data set and creates a multi index data frame.

```
dates = pd.date_range("2000-01", "2016-08", freq="MS").format(formatter=lambda x: str(x.strftime('%Y-%m')))
dates.append('State')
dates.append('RegionName')
df = pd.read_csv('City_Zhvi_AllHomes.csv', usecols=dates)
df.set_index(['State', 'RegionName'], inplace=True)
df = df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df.columns, freq='Q'), axis=1).mean()
```

Here's the output

```
df.head(2)

2000Q1  2000Q2  2000Q3  2000Q4  2001Q1  2001Q2  2001Q3  2001Q4  2002Q1  2002Q2  ... 2014Q2  2014Q3  2014Q4  2015Q1  2015Q2  2015Q3  2015Q4  2016Q1  2016Q2  2016Q3
State   RegionName                                                                                  
NY  New York    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... 515466.666667   522800.000000   528066.666667   532266.666667   540800.000000   557200.000000   572833.333333   582866.666667   591633.333333   587200.0
CA  Los Angeles 207066.666667   214466.666667   220966.666667   226166.666667   233000.0    239100.0    245066.666667   253033.333333   261966.666667   272700.0    ... 498033.333333   509066.666667   518866.666667   528800.000000   538166.666667   547266.666667   557733.333333   566033.333333   577466.666667   584050.0
2 rows × 67 columns
```

I want to calculate the mean values over quarters (each month is a separate column in the data set), which I have implemented with groupby over PeriodIndex. It works, but for some reason corrupts the data frame, as if I try to df.reset_index(), I get this

```
pandas/src/generated.pyx in pandas.algos.ensure_int64 (pandas/algos.c:64659)()

pandas/src/generated.pyx in pandas.algos.ensure_int64 (pandas/algos.c:64607)()

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'RegionName'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/tslib.pyx in pandas.tslib.parse_datetime_string_with_reso (pandas/tslib.c:32198)()

pandas/tslib.pyx in pandas.tslib.dateutil_parse (pandas/tslib.c:34509)()

ValueError: Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: REGIONNAME
```

I'm very new to Pandas, and most probably doing something wrong, I just can't figure out what. 
I want to calculate the average for each quarter (combined over every three month columns) and be able to manipulate the dataframe further.

EDIT: Here's a smaller example that reproduces the issue.

```
dates = pd.date_range("2000-01", "2000-09", freq="MS").format(formatter=lambda x: str(x.strftime('%Y-%m')))
dates.append('State')
dates.append('RegionName')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 11))
df.columns = dates
df.set_index(['State', 'RegionName'], inplace=True)
df = df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df.columns, freq='Q'), axis=1).mean()
df.reset_index()
```

Comment: can you reproduce this with a smaller example (and provide us with it)?

Comment: At the end you want only `2000Q1, 2000Q2, 2000Q3` columns and a new index without `State` and `RegionName`?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep only the aggregated values stored in the quarter columns. I also want to be flexible with indexes, e.g. later on I'd want to reset the indexes and work with them as columns

Comment: Your edited example works perfectly fine for me. What version of `pandas` are you using?

Comment: I'm using pandas 0.18.1

Answer (score 0):

```
for year in range(2000,2017):
    for quarter in range(1,5):

        if quarter == 4 and year == 2016:
            break

        new_column_name = '{0}q{1}'.format(year, quarter)
        begin_month = (quarter-1)*3 + 1
        end_month = quarter*3
        begin_column = '{0}-{1:02d}'.format(year,begin_month)
        end_column = '{0}-{1:02d}'.format(year,end_month)

        if quarter == 3 and year == 2016:
            new_column_name = '2016q3'
            begin_month = 6
            end_month = 8
            begin_column = '{0}-{1:02d}'.format(year,begin_month)
            end_column = '{0}-{1:02d}'.format(year,end_month)                

        data = housing_df.loc[:,begin_column:end_column]

        housing_df[new_column_name] = data.mean(axis = 1)
        housing_df['State'] = housing_df['State'].apply(lambda x: states[x])  
        housing_df = housing_df.set_index(['State','RegionName']) 
        ....
```

Take a look at: http://danielbreen.net/projects/housing_prices_college_towns/